# .htaccess. How to add slash to home page?

Tags: .htaccess, web

I'm trying to get rid of all possible dublicates of the main page. And right now I have 2 urls that respond with *200* status code. They are `https://host.com` and `https://host.com/`. Is there a way to redirect from `https://host.com` to `https://host.com/`?

I already tried something like this, but it didn't work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^((.*/)?[^/\.]+)$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

Comment: `https://host.com` and `https://host.com/` are not considered duplicate and in fact if you type `https://host.com/` in browser it will strip last `/`

Comment: See this question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Comment: "if you type `https://host.com/` in browser it will strip last `/`" - note that this is purely cosmetic (in the address bar). The browser is still essentially making a request for `https://host.com/` (with a trailing slash). Look at the network traffic in the browser - the two requests are identical.